# Can you make your own type function using a defining function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to create a function so I thought of trying to make type function and here is what I tried:

```
def value_type(X):
    if X == int:
        print ("integer")
    elif X == str:
        print ("string")
    else: 
        print ("floating-point number")
```

Now I know what the mistake is here. It is that int and str are function not a value.

But the question is, what should I use instead of them?

Comment: You can in fact check if a type equals `int` or `str`.  You can use `type(v) == int`, or `type(v) is int`, or `isinstance(v, int)`.  There are differences between them which you should try to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
def valu(x):
if type(x)==int:
    print("integer")
elif type(x)==str:
    print("string")
else:
    print("floting point")


valu()
```